# only first mat-input behave normal

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular2-forms

I have strange situation with my MatDialog.

I putted there two matInputs, and first works normally, but second is weird. For example when I start typing, the "label" don't go up.

Please look at image.
[image]

```
<form >
  <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0"><tr>
    <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="First name">
    </mat-form-field></td>
    <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Long Last Name That Will Be Truncated">
    </mat-form-field></td>
  </tr></table>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code behaves normally for me (both labels going up), do you have any custom css or anything that could interfere with the normal behaviour?

Comment: @bugs only that, this code is inside MatDialog

Comment: What version of `@angular/material` do you have?

Comment: "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12"

Comment: That's probably it then. Try running `npm install @angular/material: 5.1.1`

Comment: "Could not install from "@angular/material:" as it does not contain a package.json file." -  do you have any idea?

Comment: You have to run the command in the folder where you have your package.json

Comment: i doing this in correct folder, other commands npm install ... runs successfully

Comment: Mmmm.. what about `npm update @angular/material` ?

Comment: i updated to 5.1.1 but still the same effect

Comment: It works fine for me on a dialog. Can you show the `example-full-width` class?